# Excel adding up hours and minutes correctly

Tags: excel, time, calculation

I would like to sum up values containing hours and minutes, these are not in decimal format, but hours and minutes, the problem is that if I want to sum them up the result is not correct.
wrong values are displayed with formatting in excel

A1 11.35 + 9.55 = 20.90

some more information: I know you can format the cell with the format of hours and minutes, but the problem that the values are generated by web-scraping. and if I format in hours and minutes the cell with for example the value 8:08 I have 00:28

Answer (score 2):

So, simple example:

[image]

Use `A2+B2` or `A4+B4`, respectively.

I formatted as Time compared to the general above.

However, if your times go across midnight then you need to account for that by using `C8-B8+(C8<B8)` or `MOD(C8-B8,1)`.

See this example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, but please, **notice my decimal separator** is `,` not the dot, so you'll need to change this part:

[image]

Formula in B3 is:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(B2;"@");",";":"))
```

What I do is convert the number to text with `TEXT(B2;"@")`. Now, because it's a text, you can replace chars, so I replace the comma with the `:` using `SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(B2;"@");",";":")` and at the end we use VALUE to get the decimal value of that time.

The you can sum up normally and just apply time format to sum cell (`21:30` in my image)

Comment: I can't use this formula I always get an error

Comment: @TUXOne What error? How are you using this formula?

Comment: Now I made it grace, it was a translation problem, my excel is in German, I changed the language in the preferences and then I saved and put back the German language, and I automatically translated the formula.. too bad that excel does not use a universal "language". Thank you!