# Excel Formula for Arc Distance from 2 Points on Circle

Tags: excel

***Excel Formula for Arc Distance from 2 Points on Circle***

[NB: Cross-posted on *https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1372944-excel-formula-for-arc-distance-from-2-points-on-circle.html#post5645324* for Excel-specific solutions]

We're hoping for an equation we could enter into Excel (and eventually R or Python) to calculate Arc Distance given known circumference and two points along a circle.

**Background:**
The research question we want to answer is the difference between bedtimes on successive days.  Ultimately, the consistency/stability of bedtimes across days calculated through root mean square of successive differences (RMSSD).  But getting those "difference scores" is the challenge.  Converting a 24-hr day to 86400 seconds and time of day/bedtimes from 0-86400 is easy, but a day is a *circle*, not a line.  Simple subtraction doesn't work.  If bedtime on Monday is 11:55pm (23:55) and bedtime on Tues is 12:00am (00:00), the deviation is +5 minutes.  However, subtracting 00:05 - 23:55 = -23:50, obviously not the 5 min difference in actual bedtimes.

It seems like Arc Distance may able to resolve this.  If all we know is the circumference of the circle and the two points along the circle, is there a formula--specifically something we could enter in Excel (eventually codify/automate in R or Python)--that can calculate arc distance between two points?

**Example Data:**
Some example data below.  If needed for arc distance, the circumference is 86400 (number of seconds in 24-hr day), and the bedtimes could be converted to 0-86400 scale.  The challenge is how to get accurate difference scores, or shortest distance between two points on a circle.

| Day | Bedtime | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03:00 |  |
| 2 | 22:00 | -05:00 |
| 3 | 23:00 | 01:00 |
| 4 | 23:00 | 00:00 |
| 5 | 04:00 | 05:00 |
| 6 | 00:00 | -04:00 |

Answer (score 1):

So just to prove that 23:20 and 23:10 gives 10 minutes:

[image]

And using the form as suggested in the linked answer in the comment works as well:

```
A2-B2+(A2<B2)
```

And the [link to my fuller answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319003/4961700).