# How to find if x is greater than specific time, even if it's next day?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 cells in excel A - Clock In Time and B - Clock  Out Time.
I need to find out anything with clock-out time that is greater than 8pm.

I'm currently using the following formula in excel:

```
=IF(B2>=(--"8:00 PM"),"Yes","No")
```

But I'll run into an issue if my clock-out time is the next day. For example,

```
Clock In time = 11/2 8 am 
Clock Out time = 12/2 12 am
```

The clock out time is technically > 8pm of the same day. How should I better modify my formula to suit this use case?

Comment: In `B2` cell time is entered with date or only time. If only time then not possible.

Comment: Have a look at the across midnight version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319003/4961700

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:  `=B2>INT(A2)+"8:00 PM"`

Comment: This works! Can I understand what's the logic behind?

Comment: @YennyHoo `INT(A2) + "8:00PM"` is 8 PM on the start date.  So if `B2` is later=>TRUE.