# Calculate hours when working past the end of day into the next

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an Excel pay calculator. Cell F3 is the determining factor on how it calculates my regular hours, OT hours and DT hours. My clock in time is in cell D10 and my clock out time is in F10.

If you download the Excel sheet, ignore the "standard hours". That's just a reference and the OT/DT isn't always correct per my contract. [Excel sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/t/kUhFxkd5Y7CnsY0b)

1st and 2nd shift work until the day is rolled over.

Say for example, 2nd shift was told to stay late (rolled over to the next day). It gives a negative number.
3rd shift hours doesn't compute correctly at all.
If 1st shift was called in the day before (11pm) and work till their normal clock out time it doesn't calculate correctly.

Basically, I just need to know how to compute when working past the day into the next.

Each row/day has their own modules but I've been playing with Monday to make it right before I fix all the other modules.

The rules: If F3=1, regular hours is between 6am and 2pm (can come in late). Any 2 hours over regular hours is OT. OT = max of 2 hours. Any hours over OT = DT. Gets very messy when nesting for all shifts.

```vb
Public Sub Monday()
    Dim startTime As Date
    Dim endtime As Date
    Dim regHours As Double
    Dim otHours As Double
    Dim dtHours As Double

    ' Convert the time values to dates
     startTime = CDate(Range("D10"))
     endtime = CDate(Range("F10"))

    ' Calculate the total hours worked
     Dim totalHours As Double
     totalHours = (endtime - startTime) * 24
    
    ' Determine the time period
     timePeriod = Range("F3").Value
    
    ' Debugging output
     Debug.Print "Row: " & 10
     Debug.Print "Start time: " & startTime
     Debug.Print "End time: " & endtime
     Debug.Print "Total hours: " & totalHours

    ' Calculate the regular hours worked
    If timePeriod = 1 And Hour(startTime) >= 6 And Hour(endtime) <= 14 Then
            regHours = totalHours
    ElseIf timePeriod = 2 And Hour(startTime) >= 14 And Hour(endtime) <= 22 Then
            regHours = totalHours
    ElseIf timePeriod = 3 And ((Hour(startTime) >= 22 And Hour(endtime) <= 23) Or (Hour(startTime) >= 0 And Hour(endtime) <= 6)) Then
            regHours = totalHours
    ElseIf timePeriod = 1 And Hour(startTime) < 6 And Hour(endtime) <= 14 Then
            regHours = (Hour(endtime) - 6 + Minute(endtime) / 60)
    ElseIf timePeriod = 2 And Hour(startTime) < 14 And Hour(endtime) <= 22 Then
            regHours = (Hour(endtime) - 14 + Minute(endtime) / 60)
    ElseIf timePeriod = 3 And ((Hour(startTime) < 22 And Hour(endtime) <= 23) Or (Hour(startTime) >= 0 And Hour(endtime) < 6)) Then
            regHours = (Hour(endtime) - 22 + Minute(endtime) / 60)
    ElseIf timePeriod = 1 And Hour(startTime) < 6 And Hour(endtime) >= 14 Then
            regHours = (Hour(endtime) - 10 + Minute(endtime) / 60)
    ElseIf timePeriod = 2 And Hour(startTime) < 14 And Hour(endtime) >= 22 Then
            regHours = (Hour(endtime) - 15 + Minute(endtime) / 60)
    ElseIf timePeriod = 3 And ((Hour(startTime) < 22 And Hour(endtime) >= 23) Or (Hour(startTime) >= 0 And Hour(endtime) < 6)) Then
            regHours = (Hour(endtime) - 23 + Minute(endtime) / 60)
    ElseIf timePeriod = 1 And Hour(startTime) >= 6 And Hour(endtime) > 14 Then
            regHours = (14 - Hour(startTime) + Minute(startTime) / 60)
    ElseIf timePeriod = 2 And Hour(startTime) >= 14 And Hour(endtime) > 22 Then
            regHours = (22 - Hour(startTime) + Minute(startTime) / 60)
    ElseIf timePeriod = 3 And ((Hour(startTime) >= 22 And Hour(endtime) < 24) Or (Hour(startTime) >= 0 And Hour(endtime) <= 6)) Then
            regHours = (6 - Hour(startTime) + Minute(startTime) / 60)
    Else
            regHours = (14 - Hour(startTime) + Minute(startTime) / 60) + (Hour(endtime) - 14 + Minute(endtime) / 60)
    End If

    ' Calculate the overtime hours worked
    If totalHours > regHours And totalHours <= regHours + 2 Then
        otHours = totalHours - regHours
    ElseIf totalHours > regHours + 2 Then
        otHours = 2
    End If
    
    ' Debugging output
     Debug.Print "Regular hours: " & regHours
     
    ' Debugging output
     Debug.Print "Over Time Hours: " & otHours

    ' Calculate the double time hours worked
    If totalHours > regHours + 2 Then
        dtHours = totalHours - (regHours + 2)
    End If
    
    ' Debugging output
     Debug.Print "Double time hours: " & dtHours

    ' Output the results
     Range("H10").Value = regHours
     Range("J10").Value = otHours
     Range("L10").Value = dtHours
End Sub
```

Comment: So calculate in the sheet using formulas. Here is an example of working across midnight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319003/4961700

Comment: Once you can get the correct results on the sheet then consider automating it into vba.

Comment: I've used excel formulas but moved onto vba because of calculating time worked between certain time depending on value in f3. Too many if statement (nested) made it a mess. Using VBA made it more readable and allowed me to clean things up. If you saw my excel sheet, f3 determines how reg hr, ot and dt is going to be calculate based on time input in d10 and f10.

Comment: Well, shown you how to calculate across midnight with two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, very good support on here :D I just had to define that

> ```
> 'Convert the time values to dates
>     startTime = CDate(Range("D10"))
>     endtime = CDate(Range("F10"))
>
>  'Check to see if end time is smaller that start time
>  If endtime < startTime Then
>  'if smaller, + 1 day to endtime
>     endtime = endtime + 1
>  End If`
> ```

Now I just need to figure out how to calculate OT and DT when endtime = endtime + 1.