# Display 3 digit days in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two date columns in excel as follows

```
20:05:17:00
10:10:25:00
```

These represent the exact hours a worker has worked.

Adding these two I get `30:15:42:00`. I want the value in excel to be `1:06:15:42`

i.e. one day six hours and so on.

How can I achieve this in excel?

Comment: See this and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319003/4961700

Comment: `=TEXT(LEFT(A1,8)+LEFT(A2,8),"dd:hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: How are you adding those? In Excel, those values are text strings since they do not match a known format. Simple addition => `#VALUE!`.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the cells where you want to display the date in the required format.
- Select `Home` tab.
- At `Number` click the dropdown arrow and select `More Number Formats`.
- In `Category` select `Custom`.
- Under the Type text, type `dd:hh:mm:ss` or the characters according to the local settings of the language.