# How to Accurately Calculate Time Difference for Bike Rides Spanning Midnight in Excel?

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I am trying to calculate the time difference between two bike rides in Excel using a standard formula. However, I am facing issues when a bike ride spans across midnight to the next day, as the formula produces a negative value. I have attempted to add one to the end time if the bike ride ends on the next day, but this approach didn't work for bike rides that start and end on the same day. I am looking for a conditional formula or a different method that can accurately calculate the time difference without issues for bike rides that span across midnight. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried using a standard formula to calculate the time difference between two bike rides in Excel. However, I encountered a problem when a bike ride spans across midnight to the next day, as the formula produced a negative value. I attempted to add one to the end time if the bike ride ends on the next day, but this approach didn't work for bike rides that start and end on the same day.

I was expecting to find a conditional formula or a different method that could accurately calculate the time difference without issues for bike rides that span across midnight.

Comment: why is this tagged python? and pandas? it sounds like you are trying to do this in excel ... if dates are properly formatted it should know its the next day ...

Comment: Hi Tokugawa Mei! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Are you entering date/time or just time? Do rides ever span more than 24 hrs?

Comment: Please provide sample data in [Markdown Table format](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) for your input and the expected output. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like OP needs `MOD()` function.

Comment: see two methods of calculation I show here, vote for it if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319003/4961700

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is provided as datetimes, you can just subtract the end from the start to get the duration. If it's not in datetime format, you can change it into datetime format by adding together the date and time for both the start and end points.