# excel No of hours in a shift

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have two timestamps of when colleagues are expected on shift so an In an Out this is formatted as DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM, currently use the following code to create a lookup value, then lookup that value for hours expected on each shift in a day, while it works im not sure is the most efficient way.

`=IFERROR(IF(A2<>"",IF(FIXED((NUMBERVALUE((MOD(DaysMerged!E2,1)))*24)*100,0,TRUE)="0",2400,FIXED((NUMBERVALUE((MOD(DaysMerged!E2,1)))*24)*100,0,TRUE))&IF(FIXED((NUMBERVALUE((MOD(DaysMerged!F2,1)))*24)*100,0,TRUE)="0",2400,FIXED((NUMBERVALUE((MOD(DaysMerged!F2,1)))*24)*100,0,TRUE)),0),0)`

So this takes a date so for instance In 30/09/2023 14:00 & Out 30/09/2023 22:00 become 14002200, i then lookup this in a lookup table, which become

| Night Before | Earlies | Lates | Nights | Day After |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 |

another example would be 30/09/2023 05:00 & Out 30/09/2023 13:00 so 5001300

| Night Before | Earlies | Lates | Nights | Day After |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

What im after is a way to convert the In & Out timestamp into shift hours across 3 shifts, each shift is earlies 06:00-14:00 lates 14:00-22:00 then nights 22:00-06:00. once this is split i then need to get the hours for each shift to show how many hours the colleague is on shift for. so earlies, lates and nights are easy just get the value for them, then i have to add any overlap shift either before or after. Again i have this working, just looking for advise and efficient ways of going about this. any examples, sites etc are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: So consider what I did here, give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319003/4961700

Comment: i have found this https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/hours-worked-split-across-3-different-shifts-my-solution-only-works-when-col-a-col-b.1223593/ which is promising, doesnt quite work when for example a 5am-1pm shift, this puts 1pm in nights which is technically correct just on wrong day, so need 5 columns instead of 3, then move the 1 hour to first column which would be before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this

The idea is to renumber hours for a sequential value. From yesterday 22 to tomorrow 14

- Need two additional columns to shorten formula . Columns C and D. They can be hidden later.
- Formula in column C2 and D2

```
    C2                      D2
=HOUR(A2)+3   =24*(INT(VALUE(B2))-INT(VALUE(A2)))+HOUR(B2)+3  'edited by comment
```

Formulas in columns from E to I

```
E2:   =IF(C2<2;8;IF(C2<9;9-C2))-IF(D2<2;8;IF(D2<9;9-D2))
F2:   =IF(C2<10;8;IF(C2<17;17-C2))-IF(D2<10;8;IF(D2<17;17-D2))
G2:   =IF(C2<18;8;IF(C2<25;25-C2))-IF(D2<18;8;IF(D2<25;25-D2))
H2:   =IF(C2<26;8;IF(C2<33;33-C2))-IF(D2<26;8;IF(D2<33;33-D2))
I2:   =IF(C2<34;8;IF(C2<41;41-C2))-IF(D2<34;8;IF(D2<41;41-D2))
```

Result:

[image]

This version calculates with minutes in the time.

- Formula in column C2 and D2

```
    C2                      D2
=A2-INT(A2)+3/24   =1*(INT(VALUE(B2))-INT(VALUE(A2)))+B2-INT(B2)+3/24
```

Formulas in columns from E to I

```
E2:   =IF(C2<1/24;8/24;IF(C2<9/24;9/24-C2))-IF(D2<1/24;8/24;IF(D2<9/24;9/24-D2))
F2:   =IF(C2<9/24;8/24;IF(C2<17/24;17/24-C2))-IF(D2<9/24;8/24;IF(D2<17/24;17/24-D2))
G2:   =IF(C2<17/24;8/24;IF(C2<25/24;25/24-C2))-IF(D2<17/24;8/24;IF(D2<25/24;25/24-D2))
H2:   =IF(C2<25/24;8/24;IF(C2<33/24;33/24-C2))-IF(D2<25/24;8/24;IF(D2<33/24;33/24-D2))
I2:   =IF(C2<33/24;8/24;IF(C2<41/24;41/24-C2))-IF(D2<33/24;8/24;IF(D2<41/24;41/24-D2))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi, i have tried this but i am getting negative numbers for example `| 30/09/2023 22:00 | 01/10/2023 06:00 | 25 | -687 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 0 | 0 |`

Comment: Sorry tried to format not sure how it works in comments,

Comment: @deathy Thanks for it. Change content in D2 as in the answer.

Comment: Thanks works well, just one last thing is it possible to do to decimal minutes i.e 2.25 for 2 hours 15 mins ?

Comment: @deathy No, as it works with the `Hour` function.

Comment: oh looks like back to the drawing board, my bad for not mentioning it.

Comment: i have now asked at https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1413343-number-of-hours-per-shift-inlcuding-minutes.html#post5879414 as i need to be able to include minutes if anyone can help ? THanks

Comment: @deathy Pls. find the last version.

Comment: appreciate your help again, however this is now referring to as time and not decimal hours like before, so 14:00 to 21:15 should equal to 7.25. sorry if i was not clear on that.

Comment: @deathy This depends on the cell format, that you have to set. For test purposes it is better to check the time in this format that like 2.453213

Comment: This is what i have  `30/09/2023 01:20 | 30/09/2023 17:00 | 0.180555556 | 0.833333333 | 0.194444444 | 0.333333333 | 0.125 | 0 | 0`

Comment: @deathy That's right. This is the time as windows coding the date/time as a value. This result is in days, therefore multiply it with 24.

Comment: I can confirm that works, i added *24 to the end of Cols E to I and got incorrect numbers however if i do =cell*24 it works, unfortunately i have just found an issue `30/09/2023 22:00 | 01/10/2023 06:00 | 1.041666667  | 1.375 | 0 | 0 | 2.42539E-12 | 0.333333333 | 0` not sure what 2.42539E-12 is but im assuming an infinite number ?

Comment: @deathy Cols E to I  edited.

Comment: Kind of worked but numbers are not rounding correctly, and also cant do *24 in Cols E to I but works if i do it from another cell. `30/09/2023 06:00 | 30/09/2023 | 14:01 | 0.375 | 0.709027778 | 0 | 0.333333333 | 0.000694444 | 0 | 0` This results in 8 hours 2 minutes.

Comment: @deathy What means cant do *24? use parentheses =(previous exp)*24. Rounding is Excel not the formula. Check it with this A1: =Time(8,0,0) B1: =Time(0,1,0) C1: =SUM(A1:B1)*24 Result: 8,016666667

Comment: So i tried =IF(C2<25/24;8/24;IF(C2<33/24;33/24-C2))-IF(D2<25/24;8/24;IF(D2<33/24;33/24-D2))*24 and i have also tried =(IF(C2<25/24;8/24;IF(C2<33/24;33/24-C2))-IF(D2<25/24;8/24;IF(D2<33/24;33/24-D2)))*24 both were returning negative values.

Comment: i wrapped it round with a value() first then *24 and this worked thanks for all your help.