# Hours between two dates and 2 shifts

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, hour

I need to calculate total hours between two dates, considering two shifts: `06:30-16:30` and `18:30-04:30`, from Monday to Friday, excluding weekends.

start date with time start date with time Overtime   Shift 1(`06:30:00-16:30:00`)    Shift 2(`18:30-04-30`)
`20-11-2023` `06:30:00`  `24-11-2023` `15:00:00`  `00:00:00`

How to make a formula that calculates the Total hrs during the period for shift 1 and 2 based on input from start date/end date with time + overtime?
[image]
thanks.

I have tried many different formulas however, nothing has worked.

Comment: See this and give it a vote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319003/4961700

Answer (score 0):

1. separate date and time for both start and end fields(if your data is very big do it with vb scripting)
2. formula `Start_date + End_date + End_time - Start_time + Over_time` then format the cell to time format

```
## E1 cell
=A1+C1+D1-B1+E1
```